# Python how to cap a string from files path

Tags: python, string, split

In python2, how do I limit the length of a string from importing all **txt** files from a directory? like wordlength = 6000

```
import glob

raw_text = ""
path = "/workspace/simple/*.txt"

for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            raw_text += line

words = raw_text.split()
print(words)
```

this code only feeds in all **txt** files and prints in on screen. How do I limit it to 6000 words and only prints 6000 words?

Comment: you can add an `if` statement. `if raw_text.split()< N` then `raw_text += line`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your definition of a *word*.  If it's simply text separated by white space, it's fairly easy: count the words as they go past, and stop when you have enough.  For instance:

```
    word_limit = 6000
    word_count = 0
    for line in f:
        word_count += len(line.split())
        if word_count > word_limit:
            break
        raw_text += line
```

If you want *exactly* 6000 words, you can modify the loop to grab enough words from the last line to make 6000 exactly.

If you want to make it a little more effective, then drop **raw_text** and build **words** within the loop, one line at a time, with

```
        line_words = line.split()
        words.extend(line_words)
```

In this case, you'll want to use len(line_words) for your check.

Comment: split isnt recognized in your code there? anyway to fix that?

Comment: @nerdboy: Thanks -- I'm coding in another language today, and I used **split** as a built-in function instead of a class method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

raw_text = ""
path = "/workspace/simple/*.txt"

for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if len(raw_text.split())< N:  ###here you put your number
                    raw_text += line
                else:
                    break
words = raw_text.split()
print(words)
```

Comment: I think you mean `len(line.spilt()) < N`... Also why split twice? just put those words in the words list and print it at the end.

Comment: I understood it as the total number of words to be less than 6000 but i might have misunderstood. If so I am happy to delete the answer no pb :)

Comment: sorry I see what you did there. not very efficient though.

Comment: If you have a more efficient way please feel free to share ;)

Comment: i entered 6000 as < N or < 6000 but the document is still full size? same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting 6000 or less words from each file ?

```
import glob, sys

path = sys.argv[1]
count = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 60
words = []

for file in glob.glob(path):
    with open(file) as f: 
        words += f.read().split()[:count]

print(words)

>>>python test.py "/workspace/simple/*.txt" 6000
```

You could also set up a dictionary for words to file :

```
import glob, sys

path = sys.argv[1]
count = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 60
fwords = {}

for file in glob.glob(path):
    with open(file) as f: 
        fwords[file] = f.read().split()[:count]

print(fwords)
```

If you want only files with the count of words in them

```
for file in glob.glob(path):
    with open(file) as f: 
        tmp = f.read().split()
        if len(tmp) == count :  # only the count 
            fwords[file] = tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        word_limit = 12000
        word_count = 0
        for line in f:
            word_count += len(line)
            if word_count > word_limit:
                break
            raw_text += line
```

Comment: great! thanks for sharing your solution, feel free to upvote who helped you.